# ActiveMQ 5.x - XInclude doesn't seem to work in configuration files

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.x, and I'd like to pull out some of the stuff in activemq.xml brokers into separate files. Note: I cannot use `<import>` it won't work.

I would like to use XInclude in the activemq.xml configuration file.

However when I try to do it, I get an error "cannot find element xi:include"

Here is the activemq.xml file I am using. Can you please help me figure out how to get external files included?

**activemq.xml**

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>      
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker. 
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true">

        <!--
            For better performances use VM cursor and small memory limit.
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

            Also, if your producer is "hanging", it's probably due to producer flow control.
            For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
        -->

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
                  <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                    <vmCursor />
                  </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
                  <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
                       For more information, see:

                       http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

                  <pendingQueuePolicy>
                    <vmQueueCursor/>
                  </pendingQueuePolicy>
                  -->
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy> 


        <!-- 
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in 
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by 
            the JVM. For more information, see: 

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html 
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!-- 
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag). 
            For more information, see: 

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html 
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will 
            use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html

        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>
        -->

        <!-- 
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see: 

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html 
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <xi:include href="transport-connectors.xml" parse="xml"/>
    </broker>

    <!-- 
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details 
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

**transport-connectors.xml**

```
<transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

This does not work. Here is the error I get.

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The
>   matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for
>   element 'xi:include'.

I also tried using entity definitions, and just could not figure out how to get this to work.

Please recommend changes to activemq.xml that can get this to work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - there is no support for this in activemq.

After investigation, I see Activemq does not have XInclude supported/turned-on in Spring 3.0 and it requires extending Spring XML handler classes that alter the DocBuilder to allow XIncludes.

I created a new feature request to suggest this be added https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3886

Bummer.